# Debian Routing 4 Networks (2 ISP, 2 Local)

Tags: linux, debian, routing

I got my two ISPs:

- 10.100.36.0/29
- 10.200.36.0/29

I got my two networks:

- 10.45.13.0/27
- 10.45.15.0/27

I am able to route 1 ISP to my network using my debian server. However, we now have 2 LANs and 2 ISPs.

I want to route everything coming from `10.45.13.0/27` to `10.100.36.0/29` and `10.45.15.0/27` to `10.200.36.0/29`.

My debian server is a DHCP server and DNS server. It has 4 NIC cards. IPs are :

- 10.100.36.2 (eth0)
- 10.200.36.2 (eth3)
- 10.45.13.1 (eth1)
- 10.45.15.1 (eth2)

I've been searching on google since yesterday but nothing on my solution here and I barelly understand the routing system.

My system is brand new by the way,

Thanks you.

**EDIT**

```
root@ROUTER-DEB:/sst# ip route
10.200.36.0/29 dev eth3 proto kernel scope link src 10.200.36.2 metric 30
10.100.36.0/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.36.2 metric 40
10.45.15.0/27 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 10.45.15.1 metric 10
10.45.13.0/27 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.45.13.1 metric 10
default via 10.45.15.1 dev eth2 scope link metric 10
default via 10.45.13.1 dev eth1 scope link metric 10
default via 10.200.36.1 dev eth3 metric 30
default via 10.100.36.1 dev eth0 metric 40
```

Comment: The nexthop IPs for the networks are missing. You can't route to a network, just to a host address.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Can you give me an hint on how to preceed please

Comment: I request information that is necessary for provoding a solution and **that** is your "answer"? Or is that your way of saying "I don't know what the nexthops are"? What is the output of `ip route`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I don't know how route work. I never played with that so, no I don't. I edited to add my `ip route`. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know how route works, maybe you should find somebody who does? You need policy routing.

Comment: @SandorMarton I understand the logic behind it, I just don't know how to do it... I just want help to get simple command I can start from at least ... All I find online are 2 ISPs to 1 Network or 1 on 1 which I already know how to do.

Comment: Your current routing looks really evil. You may not (at least as a non-expert) have several default entries. It does not make any sense to configure your LAN as default. Surprising that you have Internet connectivity at all with that system (have you?).

Comment: @HaukeLaging I don't. Currently in my build I only installed the debian OS and the DHCPd server. I also did try to put metric on the connection in order to use Internet (like under Windows), but without success. I know I have to route everything from one network to the other I just don't know how when you have 4 networks and not 3 or less.

Comment: My recommendation: Delete the whole network configuration and start with configuring one card. One on an ISP net. And don't activate another until you have Internet connectivity for the system itself. Because fiddling with a complex configuration around a non-working system is evil. You never know whether you have done something right or wrong because it doesn't work either way...

Comment: Okay, will do tomorrow. Will delete eth1, eth2, eth3 and start by eth0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need advanced routing, source routing in this case. You need two routing tables (one for each ISP) and at least one rule for table selection.

1. Add two lines to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`. The numbers don't matter; this is just for using names instead. Let's call the tables isp_100 and isp_200.
2. Define the routing tables:

   ```
   ip route add default via 10.100.36.1 table isp_100
   ip route add 10.100.36.0/29 dev eth0 src 10.100.36.2 table isp_100
   ip route add default via 10.200.36.1 table isp_200
   ip route add 10.200.36.0/29 dev eth3 src 10.200.36.2 table isp_200
   ```
3. Define the rules for table selection

   ```
   ip rule add type unicast iif eth1 priority 100 table isp_100
   ip rule add type unicast iif eth2 priority 101 table isp_200
   ```

You could use `from 10.45.13.0/27` instead of `iif eth1`. Doesn't make a difference if nothing more than 10.45.13.0/27 is behind eth1. Interface names may change. But if later a subnet behind 10.45.13.0/27 is created then `from 10.45.13.0/27` wouldn't work any more. On the other hand: In that case the routing on this system would have to be adapted anyway. So make your choice. Most important is that you remember what you have to adapt in case of changes to the network (or system hardware).

Your main routing table defines how the system itself (locally generated packets) connects to the Internet.

You may need a script that executed the `ip route` commands every time the network subsystem is restarted. My experience with openSUSE is that a subsystem restart does not affect the `ip rule` settings. So these probably need be done only once after system boot.

You can check the current rules by `ip rule` and the tables by `ip route table isp_100`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I did try it today with the `from IP` but it didn't work. I'll try again tomorrow at work with the iif. The `ip rule` gave me last thing as before so I think I just didn't do it right in the first place.

Comment: Also. Do I need to clear the table before I put the route you gave me ?

Comment: @DavidBélanger What I showed you above is an addition to your normal routing table. Thus in general that one need not be cleared (but in this special case it need be as it's quite broken).

Comment: I was able to make it work with what you see there : http://serverfault.com/questions/507380/unable-to-ping-gateway-from-network